# How to update widget UI on data change iOS 8 Today Extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios8, widget

I need to confirm these things

1. Does widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler called by notification center it self or we manually call it in some way?
2. If we don't have widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler control then how can we update the data on data change (i am using a service to fetch json feeds from URL)

Here is what i have noticed.

1. widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler is called just once when the widget is loaded.
2. viewWillAppear/DidAppear called on switching between today and notification.

Though i have read tutorials and other stuffs about it but this is the specific point which i am unable to understand. I haven't pasted any code here as it's a more of a conceptual thing.

Kindly share knowledge about NCWidgetProviding delegates.

***Updated:***
To enable the widget to update its view when it’s off-screen make the following changes to the `widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler`. ***The system takes a snapshot of the widget and periodically***, will try to update it. If it updates successfully, the function calls the system-provided completion block with the NCUpdateResult.NewData enumeration. If the update wasn’t successful, then the existing snapshot is used.